# Create a Dictionnary from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe data :

```
    Cluster PageId  OsId    BrowserId   
0   0      1005581  11       16 
1   0      1016529  11       16 
2   0      1016529  11       17
```

and a variable comb which contains a list of values combinations of OsId and BrowserId variables  :

```
comb=list(set(product(data['OsId'], data['BrowserId'])))
```

So i would like to create a dictionary that conatains comb list as keys and PageId as values .

I try this code :

```
comb=list(set(product(data['OsId'], data['BrowserId'])))
dico={}
dico[list('comb')] = list(data['PageId'])
```

But i got this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_399512/234824120.py in <module>
      2 comb=list(set(product(data['OsId'], data['BrowserId'])))
      3 dico={}
----> 4 dico[list('comb')] = list(data['PageId'])
      5 get_ipython().run_line_magic('pinfo', 'dico')

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list
```

Any idea please to fix this error ?

Thanks

Comment: use tuples instead of list, since lists are mutable and therefore not hashable

Comment: here? dico[list('comb')] = list(data['PageId']) i replace list by tuple?

Comment: when I try : comb=list(set(product(data['OsId'], data['BrowserId'])))
dico={}
dico[tuple('comb')] = list(data['PageId'])   I got not correct dictionnary keys

Comment: put new code in question - it will be more readable.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect with `dico[list('comb')]`. It uses string `"comb"`, not list `comb`. Better show in question expected result for your data. maybe it will need to use `for`-loop to create every column separatelly.

Comment: if you have `pandas` then maybe better to use `df.groupby()` instead of `set(product())`

Comment: it would be much simpler if you would put data as code `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` or even create minimal working code - so we could simply copy it, test it and use in solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in code.

First: you use string `"comb"` instead of list comb,

Second: `dico` needs tuples (instead of lists) as keys

But the biggest problem is that `dico` is `dictionary` and dictinary doesn't work like `pandas.DataFrame` and it needs `for`-loop to create every item separatelly.

```
dico = {}

comb = set(product(data['OsId'], data['BrowserId']))

for key in comb:
    mask = (data['OsId'] == key[0]) & (data['BrowserId'] == key[1])
    values = data[ mask ]
    dico[key] = values['PageId'].to_list()
```

But it could be simpler if you would use `.groupby(...)` instead of `set(product(...))`

```
dico = {}

groups = data.groupby(['OsId', 'BrowserId'])

for key, values in groups:
    dico[key] = values['PageId'].to_list()
```

---

Full working example with both methods.

Result: `dico: {(11, 16): [1005581, 1016529], (11, 17): [1016529]}`

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

data = pd.DataFrame([
        [0,1005581,11,16],
        [0,1016529,11,16], 
        [0,1016529,11,17],
    ],
    columns=['Cluster','PageId','OsId','BrowserId']
)

print('\n--- df ---\n')
print(data)

print('\n--- set(product()) ---\n')

dico = {}

comb = set(product(data['OsId'], data['BrowserId']))

for key in comb:
    mask = (data['OsId'] == key[0]) & (data['BrowserId'] == key[1])
    values = data[ mask ]

    print('key:', key)
    print(values)
    print()

    dico[key] = values['PageId'].to_list()

print('dico:', dico)

print('\n--- groups ---\n')

dico = {}

groups = data.groupby(['OsId', 'BrowserId'])

for key, values in groups:
    print('key:', key)
    print(values)
    print()
    dico[key] = values['PageId'].to_list()
    
print('dico:', dico)
```